# FM-OLS regression: serial correlation and heteroscedasticity check

Tags: autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity, cointegration

If I am using [FM-OLS](https://ideas.repec.org/p/cwl/cwldpp/1047.html) regression to estimate the long run relationship of co-integrated I(1) variables, do I need to check for serial correlation and heteroscedasticity or is it already corrected by the FM-OLS?

Comment: What does *FM* stand for in *FM-OLS*?

Comment: it stands for fully modified

Comment: Where could we find a description of FM-OLS? Could you give a reference?

Comment: http://www.eviews.com/online_help/helpintro.html#page/EViews%209%20Help/nsreg.036.3.html

Comment: this test is provided by EVIEWS as one of three tests to estimate long run coefficients. the test makes two modifications. one for serial correlation and the other for endogeneity problem. so this means that one should check for heteroscedasticity . however, studies which have used this test or even dynamic ols regression didn't check for heteroscedasticity.

Comment: one lecturer told me in case of co-integrated variables no need to check heteroscedasticity. maybe it is related to the fact that coefficients are super consistent in this case . i don't know that is why i am asking. i am new in econometrics.